# Expandable listview; onitemClick

Tags: android, expandablelistview, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

I want to make an expandable `listview` that should respond when the user clicks on one of the items/children of the `listview` (onChildClickListener?). Can anyone help with the code? I have already made an expandable `listview` in which I have made my own adapter and dataprovider classes, but I do not know how to code the `onItemClick` part.

Answer (score 7):

You need to set separate click listeners for child and group item as follows

```
    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long l) {
            Item item = (Item) topicListAdapter.getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
            handleClick(item);
            return false;
        }
    });
    expandableListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int groupPosition, long l) {
            Item item = (item) topicListAdapter.getGroup(groupPosition);
            handleClick(item);
            return false;
        }
    });
```